# SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime crash on windows xp

Tags: c++, windows-xp

The time function in the same code crashes on xp but runs fine on windows 2003 machine. Any ideas?

```
    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION   tzi;

    SYSTEMTIME              stStartUTC;

    SYSTEMTIME              stStart;

    LPCSTR                  lpszZone;

    BOOL                    bStatus;

    FILETIME*                pFT;

    DWORD  dReturn;

    pFT = new FILETIME;

if (pFT)

{

    pFT->dwHighDateTime = 4294967295ul;
    pFT->dwLowDateTime = 4294962295ul;

    if (pFT)
    {
        FileTimeToSystemTime (pFT, &stStartUTC);
    }
    else
    {
        GetSystemTime (&stStartUTC);
    }


    dReturn = GetTimeZoneInformation (&tzi);

    bStatus = SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime (&tzi, &stStartUTC, &stStart);

}
```

Stack from the crash dump is :

> 0816e968 7c85a6f2 00000000 00000024
>   7c85a6f8
>   kernel32!__report_gsfailure+0xda
>
> 0816ebf8 7c85a788 0816ec10 0816ec70
>   0000a8f0
>   kernel32!FindRegTziForCurrentYear+0x1a5
>
> 0816ec3c 7c85a7bd 0816ec70 0000a8f0
>   0816eec4
>   kernel32!CheckDynamicTimeZoneInformation+0x29
>
> 0816ec54 7c85a834 0816ec70 0000a8f0
>   0816eec4
>   kernel32!GetDynamicTimeZoneInfoForTimeZone+0x17
>
> 0816ee7c 7c83b11c 0000a8f0 00000000
>   0816eec4
>   kernel32!GetTimeZoneInformationForYear+0x58
>
> 0816f020 14f27e38 0816f05c 0816f03c
>   0816f04c
>   kernel32!SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime+0x3c

Thanks,
Mithuna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `GetLastError` call to check if every function upto the `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime` succeeds or not. That should give you some hint.

Comment: GetLastError shows the return of the FileTimeToSystemTime returns 0, which is an error & the formated output of the error shows parameter incorrect. I know for sure the parameters are incorrect but wonder what caused the crash or heap corruption. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The __report_gsfailure on the stack frame is significant.  That's a CRT function that's called when a security error was detected.  Review the /GS command line options for the MSVC compiler.  The most common cause is a corrupted stack frame.

I see no obvious reason in your code snippet for this mishap, it is already deeply nested inside Windows.  Maybe corruption in the registry that in turn causes a buffer overflow.  You should be able to find out where by using SysInternals' ProcMon utility.